# Visual Studio 2013 - Can't login (the popup frame bugs out)

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

> *Edit* The issue was solved. It seems that using the registry value **RealTimeIsUniversal** = 1 messes up with the authentication procedure. There seems to be many other issues present if one uses this value, this being one of them.

I've experienced a weird issue when connecting my Visual Studio 2013 to my SharePoint development site. I use the IDE for easier deployment, but today this just happened out of nowhere:

[image: The login issue as follows.]
When I login I get redirected to the root team site of the domain. The expected behavior would be that the window closes and that VS13 can now upload the project solution to the assigned site, but it sadly gets stuck in this infinite loop where it asks me to always login, otherwise it forces me to work in Offline mode.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I am also considering to reset the program appdata/cache if this lasts much longer. :)

Thank you!

> Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate SP1,
>
> SharePoint 2013 on Office 365 Enterprise

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer, so that you can mark it as your solution and that way help future readers

Comment: Where is the registry value RealTimeIsUniversal = 1 placed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the popup.

1) make sure that https://login.microsoftonline.com
https://*.sharepoint.com
 in your trusted zone. 
2) Create a local user on your computer ( not bonded to a domain )

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and the bios clock on my computer was off by 15 minutes from the world clock. Resetting the bios clock corrected the problem. Strange but true.

NOTE: I corrected the Windows time before resetting the bios clock but apparently Microsoft checks the bios clock every hour and resets it which is why you should go into the bios to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when working with two different Azure accounts.

Making sure that I'm logged in in IE with the same account solved the problem for me.